# requests_html and pyinstaller

Tags: python, pycharm

When I run pyinstaller on my main.py file, it produces an exe file which outputs "Certain functionality requires requests_html, which is not installed". I installed it used `pip install reqests_html` and made a new .exe file, but it still outputs the same warning. Any idea how to fix this and remove this warning?

Answer (score 0):

I am presuming you didn't pip install this package within pycharm's venv? Pycharm creates virtual environments (`venv`s), which it runs python from, by default. So if you need to add a package, you need to add it to the correct venv. You can do this easily through the UI by going to

File -> Settings... -> Project -> Python Interpreter -> click the + button in the bottom left
[image: add package button]

Then search for the packages you need to add and click `install`.